# How to turn off a subscription in meteor

Tags: meteor

From the docs:

> Sophisticated clients can turn subscriptions on and off to control how much data is kept in the cache and manage network traffic. When a subscription is turned off, all its documents are removed from the cache unless the same document is also provided by another active subscription.

How is a subscription turned off? Example code below.

---

Client and server:

```
Rooms = new Meteor.Collection("rooms");
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish("rooms", function () {
  return Rooms.find();
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("rooms");
...
//Now turn off the subscription
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor.subscribe() returns a handle which you can call the stop method on.

```
//subscribe
roomSubscription = Meteor.subscribe("rooms");

//stop subscription
roomSubscription.stop();
```

more info on this here: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe